# Поиск и вывод из БД по фильтру. Python

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram, sqlite3

Не получается сделать адекватный вывод информации по поиску в строке. Пробовал сделать как показан код ниже, через LIKE запрос в БД, ничего не вышло толкового. Еще пробовал через `if data['country'] in read`. Ошибки ни какой не показывает, ничего не происходит. С питоном работаю недавно, особо в нем пока еще не разобрался. Буду рад, если поможете.

Основной код:

```
class FMSuser_search_counrty(StatesGroup):
    country = State()

@dp.callback_query_handler(text='is_country')
async def del_book_callback_run(call: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    await FMSuser_search_counrty.country.set()
    await call.message.reply('Введите страну события', reply_markup=user_kb.kb_user_cancel)
    await call.answer()

@dp.message_handler(state=FMSuser_search_counrty)
async def country_search_item(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data2:
        data2['country'] = message.text
    await sqlite_db.sql_read_book_search_country(state)
    await show_item_search_country(message, state)
    await state.finish()



async def show_item_search_country(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    read = await sqlite_db.sql_read_book_search_country(state)
    if len(read) == 0:
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f'Ничего не найдено.', reply_markup=user_kb.kb_user)
    else:
        for ret in read:
            if ret[4] == None:
                await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f'Наименование: {ret[0]}\nДата: {ret[1]}\nСтраны: {ret[2]}\nОписание: {ret[3]}\n', reply_markup=user_kb.kb_user)
            else:
                await bot.send_photo(message.from_user.id, ret[4], f'Наименование: {ret[0]}\nДата: {ret[1]}\nСтраны: {ret[2]}\nОписание: {ret[3]}\n', reply_markup=user_kb.kb_user)
```

Код работы с БД:

```
async def sql_read_book_search_country(state):
    cur = base.cursor()
    async with state.proxy() as data2:
        return cur.execute(f'SELECT * FROM book WHERE country LIKE ?', tuple(data2.values())).fetchall()
```

Comment: если вам необходимо отфильтровать по странам, то используйте `=` 
Например можно так
`cur.execute("SELECT * FROM book WHERE country='{country}'".format(country=country).fetchall()`
если же нужно отфильтровать сразу по нескольким странам, то что то такое
`cur.execute("SELECT * FROM book WHERE country in ({countries})".format(countries=countries).fetchall()`
может быть поможет

Comment: Не совсем понял что это. Мне нужно как-то организовать поиск подстроки в строке. К примеру:
В базе данных лежит значение "Российская империя", когда пользователь вводит "Российская", "империя" или "Росс" необходимо, чтобы он выводил все схожие с этим запросом записи.

Comment: тогда попробуйте вот так
`cur.execute("SELECT * FROM book WHERE country LIKE '{country}' ".format(country=country).fetchall()`
у меня тоже периодически бывают проблемы с передачей `args` в курсор, поэтому использую `format` но в этом случае `country` должен гарантировано существовать. Если не получится пишите, попробую воспроизвести локально.
UPD: `country` это `string`, из вашего примера `country` может быть `Российская`